# Installed SQL Server 2008, but no SQL Server Management Studio icon

Tags: sql-server-2008, installation

I installed Microsoft SQL Server 2008, but there is no `SQL Server Management Studio` icon.

All the tutorials I found on installing SQL Server 2008 say that in order to start it, I need to go `Start -> All programs -> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 -> SQL Server Management Studio`, but the icons in the Microsoft SQL Server 2008 are

- `Import and Export Data (32-bit)`
- folder `Configuration Tools` in which are three icons:

  - `SQL Server Configuration Manager`
  - `SQL Server Error and Usage Reporting`
  - `SQL Server Installation Center`

I have Windows 7.

Comment: First link on Google: http://connectsql.blogspot.com/2009/07/how-to-install-sql-server-management.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if Management Studio is installed by default, but I know there is an option to select it during setup.  You may have just missed it.  You may be able to go back into setup and tell the installer to install Management Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Run the installer again and make sure you check the Management Tools as well.

BTW: what version have you installed? Express or Standard? Express comes in different downloads

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed the Express version, there are two downloads.  **Express** and **Express with Tools**.  Check out this link for more information (it's R2, but 2008 was the same say): http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/express.aspx

If you do not have Express or you do have the Express With Tools version, then when you install SQL Server (run the install package) you'll have a bunch of check boxes for what components to install.  One of those is management tools.  You'll need that selected to have SQL Server Management Studio installed with the instance (or a stand alone install).